# How do I disable couchdb continuous replication through the API

Tags: couchdb

I don't have access to futon interface on my production server. If I need to disable continuous replication how do I do that through curl/the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CouchDb docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Cancel_replication):

> Starting from CouchDB version 1.2.0, the original replication object
>   no longer needs to be known. Instead a simple JSON object with the
>   fields "replication_id" (a string) and "cancel" (set to the boolean
>   true value) is enough. The names _local_id and id are aliases to
>   replication_id. The replication ID can be obtained from the original
>   replication request (if it's a continuous replication), from
>   _active_tasks or from the log. Example:

```
$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d ' {"source": "http://myserver:5984/foo", "target": "bar", "create_target": true, "continuous": true} '
{"ok":true,"_local_id":"0a81b645497e6270611ec3419767a584+continuous+create_target"}

$ curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d ' {"replication_id": "0a81b645497e6270611ec3419767a584+continuous+create_target", "cancel": true} '
{"ok":true,"_local_id":"0a81b645497e6270611ec3419767a584+continuous+create_target"}
```